# Android can't parse string to date

Tags: java, android, date

I have this string

```
Wed, 08 Jan 2014 9:30 am WET
```

and needed to be parsed to a Date object, I tried lot of masks but didn't work, here is the last thing I tried that I thought it would work with but didn't

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm aaa z", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

thanks

stack trace

```
01-08 14:25:25.906: W/System.err(13288): java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed, 08 Jan 2014 11:59 am WET"
01-08 14:25:25.914: W/System.err(13288):    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:626)
```

I ended up using this instead

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat     = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm aaa", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date date = dateFormat.parse(dateString.substring(0, dateString.length() - 4));
```

that `WET` part was the cause so I removed it, it wouldn't give the exact time but I only need the day and month,

Comment: that's what I found at Oracle web site

Comment: What is the WET at the end?

Comment: no idea, I think it's the zone, I got this from yahoo's website

Answer (score 5):

Give a [`Locale`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html) to your Formatter where days and months are in English, otherwise it will use your default locale (that I presume is not English) and hence can't parse your String.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat =
      new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm aaa z", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace please, because it's working for me.

Comment: should that be `hh:mm`?

Comment: @turbo Yes I failed when I wrote it, sorry.

Comment: @user2427819 Check this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299837/simpledateformat-unparseable-date-exception